# In SQL - FIND Function

Tags: sql, function, find

I'm new to the SQL world. How do I use the `FIND` function w/o getting an error message.
I wrote

`= FIND(" ", D2)`

to find where the space is in cell `D2` (example).

Thank you kindly!

Comment: Uhh that sounds like excel not sql

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a word in a table in SQL you need to use "like" statement.
You can see this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) about, how to use it.

You can see these example.This query selects all customers with a CustomerName ending with "a":

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%';
```

If you want to know where is the word wich you need. You use "CHARINDEX" statement.
Yo can see this example.This query searches for bicycle in the searched string value variable @document. You can see more [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
DECLARE @document VARCHAR(64);  
SELECT @document = 'Reflectors are vital safety' +  
                   ' components of your bicycle.';  
SELECT CHARINDEX('bicycle', @document);
```